# set the field dependent w

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

- I need to get addicted, one field from another.
- selectbox has a list of options
- If the first or e.g. 5 option is selected in the dropdownbox, class:selectboxlist
- then I would like set value '-1' in the second column class:days_tpu
- What I was able to do is at the bottom of the post

**View:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="td01" class="@userColor1">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].PrzyczynaNieobecnosci, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Urlopy))), "  ", new { @class = "selectboxlist" })</td>

<td id="td01">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].DniOdpracowania, new { @class = "days_tpu", @readonly = true })</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I caught it properly, I would solve your issue like this:`<select asp-for="PrzyczynaNieobecnosci" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Urlopy>()" id="selectList"></select>`. 
So that in html you can see dropdown select list with values.
And javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("selectList").addEventListener("change", setSecondColumnValue);

function setSecondColumnValue() {
  var secondColumnField = document.getElementById('selectedValue');
  if(this.value == "1")
    secondColumnField.innerHTML = 1;
  else
    secondColumnField.innerHTML = 0;
}
```

Comment: GetelementById where selectlist is class? Does it work?